# How to create simple PHP array? Name the key and the value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to create a php array where I can store 2 variables for each entry, an ID and VALUE.

Like, I have some items:

```
ID   VALUE

234  55.00

456  120.25

789  20.00
```

I am trying to store them in an array somehow where later on down the page I can do something like:

YOU BOUGHT:

```
'For each item in the array, echo ID, VALUE'
```

How would this be done?

Comment: There are plenty of examples in manual: http://lv.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
<?php
$store = array(
  234 => 55,
  456 => 120.25,
  789 => 20
);

// call it like this
foreach($store as $id => $value) {
  echo 'Product with id ',$id,' has a value of ',$value,'$';
}
```

But you should do a bit more research, before asking here!

Comment: I did the research, I just don't understand a lot of it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? This would also allow you to easily extend the array without having to refactor code.

```
$stuff = array(
    234 => array(
        'value' => 55.0
    ),
    456 => array(
        'value' => 120.25
    ),
    789 => array(
        'value' => 20.0
    )
);

foreach ($stuff as $id => $data) {
    echo "ID: $id, value: {$data['value']}<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic stuff. Might wanna spend some time with a book or some tutorials...

```
$items = array(
    234 => 55.00,
    456 => 120.25,
    789 => 20.00
    );

print "You Bought:<br />";

foreach( $items as $id => $cost )
{
    print "{$id}: {$cost}<br />";
}
```

http://codepad.org/vUHpJZMw

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr[] = array(
            'id' => '1',
            'value' => 'abc'
     );

$arr[] = array(
            'id' => '2',
            'value' => 'efg'
     );
//.... etc

foreach($arr AS $r)
{
    echo $r['id'] . '=' . $r['value'];
}
```

Just an example..